# Does adding ownership of .github folder which holds the OWNERSHIP file lead to any problem?

Tags: github

The file structure of a given Git repository is as follows:

```
mainrepo
 --  .github/
 |  --  CODEOWNERS
 |  --  folderA/
 |  --  somefile
 --  folderC/
 |  --  fileDG
```

The CODEOWNERS file is as follows:

```
/mainrepo/folderC/ @team1
```

with that can I add either the .github folder or the folder inside it to CODEOWNERS without an issue? so that it looks like

```
/mainrepo/.github @team1
/mainrepo/.github/folderA/ @user2
/mainrepo/folderC/ @team1
```

[Codeowners info github link](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners)

Comment: The `.github` directory should be at the repository root, so it's odd that `mainrepo` would be part of any path in `CODEOWNERS`.